# Remove Alertdialog such that newAlertDialog() will call onCreateDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I run into the problem where onCreateDialog is called only once. This is a problem for me because i have referred to xml layouts in that method and whenever i dismiss the dialog and call it the second time, these references are gone. code below:

```
        if (position == 0){

        PlayerNameDialog playerNameDialog = PlayerNameDialog.newInstance();
        playerNameDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TeamActivity.PLAYER_DIALOG);

    }
    else {
        String playerName = teamPlayers.get(position).toString();
        Player selectedPlayer = team.FindPlayer(playerName);
        PlayerNameDialog playerNameDialog = PlayerNameDialog.newInstance();



        playerNameDialog.changePlayerName(selectedPlayer.playerName);
        playerNameDialog.changePlayerRating(selectedPlayer.playerRating);
        playerNameDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TeamActivity.PLAYER_DIALOG);

    }
```

and for my alert dialog

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_name_dialog, null);

    playerRatingSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.player_rating_sbar);
    playerRatingSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    playerRatingTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.player_rating);
    playerRatingTxtView.setText(getString(R.string.player_rating)+" "+playerRatingSeekBar.getProgress());
    playerNameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.player_name);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setView(view);



    builder.setMessage("New Player");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            mListner.onPNDialogPositiveClick(PlayerNameDialog.this, view);

        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mListner.onPNDialogNegativeClick(PlayerNameDialog.this, view);

        }
    });

    return builder.create();

}
```

the second time i create a new dialog instance (under else statement), the onCreateDialog method is no longer called. As a result all the edittext references are gone. I tried using the dimiss() and removefragment method, but did not work

Anyway to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah create another Dialog class like you should instead of trying to manually call `onCreateDialog` which you should never do

Answer (score 1):

```
try this:
 private static AlertDialog dialog;
public static void showDialog(Context context, String message) {
    if (context != null) {
        TextView textMsg;
        TextView textOk;
        LinearLayout textOKLayout;

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
        alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
        textMsg = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textOk = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textOk);
        textOKLayout = (LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textOKLayout);
        textMsg.setText(message);
        textOKLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am using dialogFragment instead of  the dialog class...